# How to remove keys from hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

How do I remove the key from an existing map?

```
if (exists $sampleMap{1})
{
      #Here I want to remove the "1" key from sampleMap
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `delete` for deleting the hash keys:

```
if (exists $sampleMap{1})
{
      delete $sampleMap{1}; #Here I want remove the "1" key from sampleMap.
}
```

For more details, take a look at [delete](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html).

Comment: You don't need to check if the key exists, delete() won't complain if it's not there.